# SQL SELECT Replace country names with abbreviations

Tags: sql

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT o.CustomerID, null emptyColumn, o.ShipFirstName, o.ShipCountry, c.EmailAddress

FROM Orders o, Customers c

WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```

And the results are like,

```
1,,John,United States,john@example.com
2,,Peter,Canada,peter@example.com
```

But I need to change "United States" to "US" and "Canada" to "Ca". How can I do this?

Comment: Do you wanna replace them in the database ?

Comment: No only in results @ImaneFateh

Comment: it is text type @Nithesh

Comment: as @Rahul Tripathi siad use `case` if only two country names there. Is the `ShipCountry` name dynamic? or only `us` and `ca`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case`,

```
SELECT  o.CustomerID, null emptyColumn, o.ShipFirstName, 
        case when o.ShipCountry = 'United States' then 'US'
        when o.ShipCountry = 'Canada' then 'CA'
        end,
        c.EmailAddress
FROM Orders o, Customers c
WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```

Comment: Could you share your code which you have tried with **case**??

Comment: yea there was an error in my syntax. do you think this approach will be fine for large range of countries as I have no other choice beside select statement?

Comment: As an alternate solution you can create a seperate table to store the Country name and Abbreviation. And use a join to fetch the appropriate result. :)

Comment: yeah just did! one last thing please. do you know how I can skip field names in first row of my export?

Comment: Could you post a seperate question for this?? As it would be easy to understand what you want to do:)

Answer (score 2):

If it's for a large range of countries, then do a search for ISO country codes ([for example](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/country_names_and_code_elements.htm)) - import that data into a new table and then join to that table.

Or put your selection of countries into a CTE and join to that, e.g.,

```
WITH Countries(ISO_Code, ISO_Name) AS
(
    SELECT
     *
    FROM (VALUES ('AF', 'AFGHANISTAN')
                ,('AX', 'ÅLAND ISLANDS')
                ,('AL', 'ALBANIA')
                ,('DZ', 'ALGERIA')
                ,('AS', 'AMERICAN SAMOA')
                ,('AD', 'ANDORRA')
                ,('AO', 'ANGOLA')
                ,('AI', 'ANGUILLA')
                ,('AQ', 'ANTARCTICA')
                ,('AG', 'ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA')) nTab(nCol1, nCol2)
)
SELECT
 *
FROM Countries c
JOIN ...
```

Comment: yeah that's nice point but unfortunately due to the restrictions of platform I can only run SELECT statement.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming along this thread as I did and looking for state abbreviations instead of countries, here's a quick copy paste of all US states and Canadian provinces in WHEN/THEN format. Adapt to your own CASE statement needs.

```
CASE "YOUR COLUMN CONTAINING FULL STATE NAMES"
WHEN 'Alabama' THEN 'AL' 
WHEN 'Alaska' THEN 'AK' 
WHEN 'Arizona' THEN 'AZ' 
WHEN 'Arkansas' THEN 'AR' 
WHEN 'California' THEN 'CA' 
WHEN 'Colorado' THEN 'CO' 
WHEN 'Connecticut' THEN 'CT' 
WHEN 'Delaware' THEN 'DE' 
WHEN 'District of Columbia' THEN 'DC' 
WHEN 'Florida' THEN 'FL' 
WHEN 'Georgia' THEN 'GA' 
WHEN 'Hawaii' THEN 'HI' 
WHEN 'Idaho' THEN 'ID' 
WHEN 'Illinois' THEN 'IL' 
WHEN 'Indiana' THEN 'IN' 
WHEN 'Iowa' THEN 'IA' 
WHEN 'Kansas' THEN 'KS' 
WHEN 'Kentucky' THEN 'KY' 
WHEN 'Louisiana' THEN 'LA' 
WHEN 'Maine' THEN 'ME' 
WHEN 'Maryland' THEN 'MD' 
WHEN 'Massachusetts' THEN 'MA' 
WHEN 'Michigan' THEN 'MI' 
WHEN 'Minnesota' THEN 'MN' 
WHEN 'Mississippi' THEN 'MS' 
WHEN 'Missouri' THEN 'MO' 
WHEN 'Montana' THEN 'MT' 
WHEN 'Nebraska' THEN 'NE' 
WHEN 'Nevada' THEN 'NV' 
WHEN 'New Hampshire' THEN 'NH' 
WHEN 'New Jersey' THEN 'NJ' 
WHEN 'New Mexico' THEN 'NM' 
WHEN 'New York' THEN 'NY' 
WHEN 'North Carolina' THEN 'NC' 
WHEN 'North Dakota' THEN 'ND' 
WHEN 'Ohio' THEN 'OH' 
WHEN 'Oklahoma' THEN 'OK' 
WHEN 'Oregon' THEN 'OR' 
WHEN 'Pennsylvania' THEN 'PA' 
WHEN 'Rhode Island' THEN 'RI' 
WHEN 'South Carolina' THEN 'SC' 
WHEN 'South Dakota' THEN 'SD' 
WHEN 'Tennessee' THEN 'TN' 
WHEN 'Texas' THEN 'TX' 
WHEN 'Utah' THEN 'UT' 
WHEN 'Vermont' THEN 'VT' 
WHEN 'Virginia' THEN 'VA' 
WHEN 'Washington' THEN 'WA' 
WHEN 'West Virginia' THEN 'WV' 
WHEN 'Wisconsin' THEN 'WI' 
WHEN 'Wyoming' THEN 'WY' 
WHEN 'Alberta' THEN 'AB' 
WHEN 'British Columbia' THEN 'BC' 
WHEN 'Manitoba' THEN 'MB' 
WHEN 'New Brunswick' THEN 'NB' 
WHEN 'Newfoundland and Labrador' THEN 'NL' 
WHEN 'Northwest Territories' THEN 'NT' 
WHEN 'Nova Scotia' THEN 'NS' 
WHEN 'Nunavut' THEN 'NU' 
WHEN 'Ontario' THEN 'ON' 
WHEN 'Prince Edward Island' THEN 'PE' 
WHEN 'Quebec' THEN 'QC' 
WHEN 'Saskatchewan' THEN 'SK' 
WHEN 'Yukon Territory' THEN 'YT' 
    ELSE NULL
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the below code will work, it will be better if you have another column in the country table with abbreviations

```
select 
    case 
    When o.ShipCountry = 'UnitedState' Then 'US'
    When o.ShipCountry = 'Canada' Then 'CA'
    ELSE o.ShipCountry
    End
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT o.CustomerID, null emptyColumn, o.ShipFirstName, o.ShipCountry = 
CASE WHEN oShipCountry ='United States' THEN 'US' 
WHEN o.ShipCountry = 'Canada' then 'CA' END, 
c.EmailAddress
FROM Orders o, Customers c
WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```